# Architecture of some Client-Server solution

Tags: java, html, architecture, client

We have a tool that should display some formated content. Users will create some templates with images and will publish them. 
We need to save these templates for further their displaying using html.
We have java server and javascript/html client.

Two solutions were proposed.

1. Server team propose to store information about images in DB which containes id, x, y (where id - image id, x,y - coordinates) of each item and generate view result dynamicaly using this data on client side.
2. Client-side team proposes to store raw html(with inline css) in DB directly.

What do you think about these solutions?
Which solution is better? 
What possible problems could happen?

Comment: Fire the client-side team. Immediately.

Comment: And if the server-side team has proposed something like mixing the coordinate info with the image in the same table, (1 on 1 relationship), don't trust them much, either.